# How to solve ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingReceiver permission check issue in Android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I developed the app in react-native My app is working fine but when I am doing the security check , I am getting below error.

"Broadcast Receiver (io.invertase.firebase.messaging.ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingReceiver) is Protected
by a permission, but the protection level of the permission should be checked."

In below code I have attached Manifest file and Java code both . Please help me solve this issue .I need to solve this before sharing this apk .

// Manifest file below

```
<receiver
      android:name=".ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingReceiver"
      android:exported="true"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

// Activity

```
package io.invertase.firebase.messaging;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ActivityEventListener;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableNativeMap;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import io.invertase.firebase.common.ReactNativeFirebaseEventEmitter;
import io.invertase.firebase.common.ReactNativeFirebaseModule;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingModule extends ReactNativeFirebaseModule
    implements ActivityEventListener {
  private static final String TAG = "Messaging";
  ReadableMap initialNotification = null;
  private HashMap<String, Boolean> initialNotificationMap = new HashMap<>();

  ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext, TAG);
    reactContext.addActivityEventListener(this);
  }

  private WritableMap popRemoteMessageMapFromMessagingStore(String messageId) {
    ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingStore messagingStore =
        ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingStoreHelper.getInstance().getMessagingStore();
    WritableMap remoteMessageMap = messagingStore.getFirebaseMessageMap(messageId);
    messagingStore.clearFirebaseMessage(messageId);
    return remoteMessageMap;
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void getInitialNotification(Promise promise) {
    if (initialNotification != null) {
      promise.resolve(initialNotification);
      initialNotification = null;
      return;
    } else {
      Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();

      if (activity != null) {
        Intent intent = activity.getIntent();

        if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
          // messageId can be either one...
          String messageId = intent.getExtras().getString("google.message_id");
          if (messageId == null) messageId = intent.getExtras().getString("message_id");

          // only handle non-consumed initial notifications
          if (messageId != null && initialNotificationMap.get(messageId) == null) {
            WritableMap remoteMessageMap;
            RemoteMessage remoteMessage =
                ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingReceiver.notifications.get(messageId);
            if (remoteMessage == null) {
              remoteMessageMap = popRemoteMessageMapFromMessagingStore(messageId);
            } else {
              remoteMessageMap =
                  ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingSerializer.remoteMessageToWritableMap(remoteMessage);
            }
            if (remoteMessageMap != null) {
              promise.resolve(remoteMessageMap);
              initialNotificationMap.put(messageId, true);
              return;
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        Log.w(
            TAG,
            "Attempt to call getInitialNotification failed. The current activity is not ready, try"
                + " calling the method later in the React lifecycle.");
      }
    }

    promise.resolve(null);
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void setAutoInitEnabled(Boolean enabled, Promise promise) {
    Tasks.call(
            getExecutor(),
            () -> {
              FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setAutoInitEnabled(enabled);
              return null;
            })
        .addOnCompleteListener(
            task -> {
              if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                promise.resolve(FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().isAutoInitEnabled());
              } else {
                rejectPromiseWithExceptionMap(promise, task.getException());
              }
            });
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void getToken(Promise promise) {
    Tasks.call(getExecutor(), () -> Tasks.await(FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()))
        .addOnCompleteListener(
            task -> {
              if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                promise.resolve(task.getResult());
              } else {
                rejectPromiseWithExceptionMap(promise, task.getException());
              }
            });
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void deleteToken(Promise promise) {
    Tasks.call(
            getExecutor(),
            () -> {
              Tasks.await(FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().deleteToken());
              return null;
            })
        .addOnCompleteListener(
            task -> {
              if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                promise.resolve(task.getResult());
              } else {
                rejectPromiseWithExceptionMap(promise, task.getException());
              }
            });
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void hasPermission(Promise promise) {
    Tasks.call(
            getExecutor(),
            () ->
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(getReactApplicationContext())
                    .areNotificationsEnabled())
        .addOnCompleteListener(
            task -> {
              if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                promise.resolve(task.getResult() ? 1 : 0);
              } else {
                rejectPromiseWithExceptionMap(promise, task.getException());
              }
            });
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void sendMessage(ReadableMap remoteMessageMap, Promise promise) {
    Tasks.call(
            getExecutor(),
            () -> {
              FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()
                  .send(
                      ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingSerializer.remoteMessageFromReadableMap(
                          remoteMessageMap));
              return null;
            })
        .addOnCompleteListener(
            task -> {
              if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                promise.resolve(task.getResult());
              } else {
                rejectPromiseWithExceptionMap(promise, task.getException());
              }
            });
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void subscribeToTopic(String topic, Promise promise) {
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()
        .subscribeToTopic(topic)
        .addOnCompleteListener(
            task -> {
              if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                promise.resolve(task.getResult());
              } else {
                rejectPromiseWithExceptionMap(promise, task.getException());
              }
            });
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void unsubscribeFromTopic(String topic, Promise promise) {
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()
        .unsubscribeFromTopic(topic)
        .addOnCompleteListener(
            task -> {
              if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                promise.resolve(task.getResult());
              } else {
                rejectPromiseWithExceptionMap(promise, task.getException());
              }
            });
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, Object> getConstants() {
    final Map<String, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
    constants.put("isAutoInitEnabled", FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().isAutoInitEnabled());
    return constants;
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // noop
  }

  @Override
  public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
      String messageId = intent.getExtras().getString("google.message_id");
      if (messageId == null) messageId = intent.getExtras().getString("message_id");

      if (messageId != null) {
        RemoteMessage remoteMessage =
            ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingReceiver.notifications.get(messageId);
        WritableMap remoteMessageMap;

        if (remoteMessage == null) {
          remoteMessageMap = popRemoteMessageMapFromMessagingStore(messageId);
        } else {
          remoteMessageMap =
              ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingSerializer.remoteMessageToWritableMap(remoteMessage);
        }

        if (remoteMessageMap != null) {
          // WritableNativeMap not be consumed twice. But it is resolved in future and in event
          // below. Make a copy - issue #5231
          WritableNativeMap newInitialNotification = new WritableNativeMap();
          newInitialNotification.merge(remoteMessageMap);
          initialNotification = newInitialNotification;
          ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingReceiver.notifications.remove(messageId);

          ReactNativeFirebaseEventEmitter emitter =
              ReactNativeFirebaseEventEmitter.getSharedInstance();
          emitter.sendEvent(
              ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingSerializer.remoteMessageMapToEvent(
                  remoteMessageMap, true));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks